# syntax error for string replacement using a dictionary function

Tags: c#

[image: errors]C# .NET 4.5.1

Syntax error "The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments.

```
public string DictionaryReplace(string str, Dictionary<string, string> map)
{
    var regex = new Regex(str.Join("|", map.Keys));
    var newStr = regex.Replace(str, m => map[m.Value]);
    return newStr;
}
```

Is this because of the .NET version I have ?

Am I using the separator in Join correctly ?

Comment: string.Join is static.

Comment: `map.Keys.ToArray()`

Comment: I would suggest reading up on this [How to use string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Are you sure you're not compiling with a pre 4.0 version of .Net?

Comment: I followed an online tutorial [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx)  My code is 378758

Comment: have you tried this without using regex.. perhaps you are not using it properly.. doing this with native C# code should work without having to use regex

Comment: Have you tried adding `ToArray()`?

Answer (score 0):

Confusingly, `string` has both static and instance `join` methods. (The latter are  extension methods that come with inheriting `IEnumerable<T>`, and, like all extension methods, are themselves defined as static methods, but operate at the instance level.)

The one you're using expects the second argument to be of type `string[]`. In order to use that one, you'd need `ToArray`:

```
str.Join("|", map.Keys).ToArray()
```

Rather than convert to an array, however, you can just use the static method:

```
string.Join("|", map.Keys)
```

Comment: The "instance" Join method is actually an extention method and it's signature is completely [different](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.join(v=vs.100).aspx).  I'm guessing the OP had a typo and was using the static method.

Answer (score -3):

SOLVED.Target Framework was set on 3.5. I set it on 4.5, it worked. Huge Sorry people. Thank you all for your help.  I only used the registry in the past to determine which version I used.  I was lucky to make it this far by thinking I was using 4.5